# Can EF5 code-first migrations be scaffolded outside of Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I am looking for a way to generate new code-first migrations (like when using `Add-Migration`) for an existing project using EF5. Due to security restrictions banning PowerShell 2.0, I'm unable to run the Package Manager Console inside Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (the newest version approved for use where I work).

I figured out how to RUN the migrations from a command line using the `migrate.exe` tool, but I have not been able to find a way to generate them. Is there something like this that I can use to generate the new migrations?